# coefficients in square of sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have the following expression:

$Ax^2 + By^2+Cz^2 + AB2xy + AC2xz + BC2yz$

I am trying to find out if the above expression is always positive.

$A,B,C$ are always positive and $x,y,z$ are always non zero

The expression looks very similar to a square of sum: $(x+y+z)^2$ but I don't know if I can factor out the $A,B,C$ coefficients.

Comment: You are allowing $A=B=C=0$, in which case the expression is not positive.

Comment: `The expression looks very similar to a square of sum` That would be a different expression:$$A^\color{red}{2}x^2 + B^\color{red}{2}y^2+C^\color{red}{2}z^2 + 2ABxy + 2ACxz + 2BCyz=(Ax+By+Cz)^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Let $A=B=C=2$, $x=1,y=z=-1$

The expression $=-2 < 0$

Answer (score 0):

No, the answer would always not be positive.One example is A=4,B=1,C=1,x=-1,y=1,z=1.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
**Hint:**
$$
\pars{x \quad y\quad z}
\pars{\begin{array}{ccc}
\ds{A} & \ds{AB} & \ds{AC}
\\
\ds{AB} & \ds{B} & \ds{BC}
\\
\ds{AC} & \ds{BC} & \ds{C}
\end{array}}
\pars{\substack{\ds{x} \\[3mm] \ds{y} \\[3mm] \ds{}z}}
$$

> Study the above matrix eigenvalues. What conditions must satisfy $\ds{A}$, $\ds{B}$ and $\ds{C}$ such that all eigenvalues $\ds{> 0 }$ ?.

Comment: It was through that multiplication that I arrived to my question but in reverse order. If the result of such operation is positive for all non zero values of x,y,z, then the matrix is positive definite and has real positive eigenvalues. If I understand correctly